# iOS Parse and Obj-c: PFKeychainStore failed to set object for key 'currentUser'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

During app execution I got sometimes this error:

```
PFKeychainStore failed to set object for key 'currentUser', with error: -34018
```

It doesn't happen always, just sometimes.
For example, I run this code in viewDidLoad

```
NSLog(@"%@", [PFUser currentUser]);

if ([ManageConnection isWiFi] || [ManageConnection isFastConnection]) {
    [[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            [ParseErrorHandlingController handleParseError:error];
        }
        else {
            self.user = (PFUser *)object;
```

When I print on console [PFUser currentUser] value, it exists

```
<PFUser: 0x6080000e8980, objectId: 5ZgXxNrT5C, localId: (null)>
```

But when I try to fetch the user I got the error above. Any suggestions?

I'm using the latest version of Parse.

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, i am bit of confuse here.
You can  get current user by [PFUser currentUser] only then why you need to fetch it again in the background?

Comment: Hi @SatishMavani, you know I'm not the owner of the code, just fixing some bugs. The previous dev wrote this func. Anyway, I often come into this error.

Comment: @SatishMavani I found out why there's that "fetch". At viewDidLoad, I need a value of [PFUser currentUser] object. Since that value might be changed, I have to update my [PFUser currentUser] object.

Answer (score 0):

To update current user, You can use below code only:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetch];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was about codesigning in iOS10. Check your provisioning profiles then try installing again.